# Regex c# questions

Tags: c#, regex

I have an html code.
I parse it with such regex

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(go, @"photoWrapper""><div><a href=""(?<id>[^""]+?)\?");
```

I receive:

```
matches[0].Groups["id"].Value = "/group/47502002094086";
matches[1].Groups["id"].Value = "/dk";
matches[2].Groups["id"].Value = "/prostooglavnom";
```

How to edit my regexp or add smth, to receive in matches only

```
matches[0].Groups["id"].Value = "47502002094086";
matches[1].Groups["id"].Value = "prostooglavnom";
```

Any help?=\
Full html code : http://pastebin.com/xEJNiD4G

Comment: You should show the HTML code you are parsing...

Comment: There's not enough information about the structure of your HTML code - please provide a relevant sample of it.

Answer (score 7):

You have just discovered for yourself why [Regex is a poor choice for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583).

I suggest you use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)  to parse and query your HTML.

The source download comes with many example projects.

> What is exactly the Html Agility Pack (HAP)?
>
> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

Comment: Saw the question title in the list and thought "even money says someone has posted a link to THAT answer"

Comment: I don't want to use this lib. I want to use regexp=\

Comment: @user1895750 - But regex is not a great option. Can you explain why the HAP is such a bad choice for you? Why does it have to be a regex?